# How to zip specific individual files in a directory

Tags: files, filenames, zip, recursive

for example, this folder `~/folder1/folder2` contains a lot of files like:

`abc_0101.txt` `abc_0102.txt` ...

`abc_0201.txt` `abc_0202.txt` ...

`abc_0301.txt` `abc_0302.txt` ...

`abc_0401.txt` `abc_0402.txt` ...

how to do zip each file in this folder for specific file names?

like i only want to zip all files like `abc_01*.txt` and `abc_03*.txt`

Comment: not that i want to zip all files into 1 zip file. i would like to zip each file as in `abc_0101.zip` `abc_0202.zip` ... `abc_0303.zip` `abc_0302.zip` ...

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward.

With zip:

```
zip zipfile.zip abc_01*.txt abc_03*.txt
```

With tar/gzip:

```
tar cvf tarball.tar.gz abc_01*.txt abc_03*.txt
```

Or did you try that and run into problems somehow?

Or did you want each file in its own zip file?

Then something like:

```
for file in abc_01*.txt abc_03*.txt ; do
    zip "${file}.zip" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name pattern will be safe to use command like this:

```
zip zipfile.zip abc_01??.txt abc_03??.txt
```

This will ensure you will compress only files with two symbols after `01` and `03`